# Reading WARC Files Efficiently

Tags: python, byte, common-crawl, warc

I am reading a WARC file with python's 'warc' library. Current file that I am using, is around 4.50 GB. The thing is ;

```
file = warc.open("random.warc")
html_lists = [line for line in file]
```

Executing these 2 lines takes up to 40 seconds. Since there will be 64000 more files like this one, it is not acceptable that it takes 40 seconds per file. Do you guys have any tips to improve performance or any different approaches?

Edit : I found out that Beautifulsoup operations take some time. So I removed it and wrote the necessary stuff myself. It is 100x faster now. It takes +- 60 seconds to read and process 4.50 GB data. With this line of code I remove the scripts from data;

```
clean = re.sub(r"<script.*?</script>", "", string=text)
```

And with this one I split the text and remove the stamp which I don't need

```
warc_stamp = str(soup).split(r"\r\n\r\n")
```

As I said it is faster but 60 seconds are not that good in this case. Any suggestions ?

Comment: What is the actual operation you want to do to the WARC? The usual case is that processing the content is a lot more expensive than just reading it.

Comment: I am reading it line by line with using "payload.read()". I will edit the question

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to achieve and what would be the processing time goal you are trying to meet?

Answer (score 2):

> but 60 seconds are not that good in this case

Of course, it would mean that processing all 64,000 WARC files takes 45 days if not done in parallel. But as a comparison: the Hadoop jobs to crawl the content of the WARC files and also those to transform WARCs into WAT and WET files need around 600 CPU days each.

WARC files are gzip-compressed because disk space and download bandwidth are usually the limiting factors. Decompression defines the baseline for any optimization. E.g., decompressing a 946 MB WARC file takes 21 seconds:

```
% time zcat CC-MAIN-20170629154125-20170629174125-00719.warc.gz >/dev/null 
real    0m21.546s
user    0m21.304s
sys     0m0.240s
```

Iterating over the WARC records needs only little extra time:

```
% cat benchmark_warc.py
import gzip
import sys
import warc

n_records = 0

for record in warc.WARCFile(fileobj=(gzip.open(sys.argv[1]))):
    if record['Content-Type'] == 'application/http; msgtype=response':
        n_records += 1

print("{} records".format(n_records))

% time python benchmark_warc.py CC-MAIN-20170629154125-20170629174125-00719.warc.gz
43799 records

real    0m23.048s
user    0m22.169s
sys     0m0.878s
```

If processing the payload only doubles or triples the time needed anyway for decompression (I cannot imagine that you can outperform the GNU gzip implementation significantly), you're close to the optimum. If 45 days is too long, the development time is better invested in parallelization of the processing. There are already plenty of examples available how to achieve this for Common Crawl data, e.g. [cc-mrjob](https://github.com/commoncrawl/cc-mrjob) or [cc-pyspark](https://github.com/commoncrawl/cc-pyspark).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It currently takes 75 seconds (with Decompressing) to process 4.5 GB file. I thought about multiprocessing, tried to implement it too but the thing is you can't pass the buffered file to a process or you can't open the file in a process. Probably each process dealing with a file would be the best way to go at this point.

Comment: Is `warc` working from python3 ? I am getting error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66794188/error-no-module-named-builtin-when-importing-warc

Comment: No, but there are forks on Github which are compatible the Python3. Alternatively, use [warcio](https://pypi.org/project/warcio/).

Answer (score 0):

Get the source code of that module, and check for optimization potential.

Use a profiler to identify performance bottlenecks, then focus on these for optimization.

It can make a huge difference to rewrite Python code in Cython and compile it into *native* code. So that is likely worth a try.

But by any means, rather than speculating on an internet forum on how to accelerate a *two line* script, you really need to work with the actual code underneath!

Comment: Yeah that is what I was thinking, I will take a look at Cython. Thanks

Comment: Don't optimize too early. First identify the bottleneck. Maybe it already *is* in native code (e.g. compression) or maybe there is an obvious way to optimize it by reducing allocations.

Comment: Yes as you said I checked the code and found out that Bsoup takes some time. So I removed it completely. I edited the question can you take a look at it? And is it okay to process 4.50 GB data in 60 seconds? Thanks in the advance !

Comment: You can try beautifulsoup using `lxml` instead of the default. LibXML can be quite a bit faster. And of course, precompile any regexp that you use frequently... I wouldn't use regexp for processing HTML tags though.

Comment: I am not using Bsoup at all anymore. Yes, I compile regexes. Why not there are lots of javascript in html pages so removing them with regex is easy and also not that costful. What do you suggest, string operations ?

Comment: There are constructs where your regexp can remove too much/too little. For example, someone could use a custom tag `<scripting>regular html formatted with CSS</scripting>` and you'll begin removing there all the way to some script at the end of the document. Or with CDATA constructs, there can be a `</script>` inside the script that will be ignored by the HTML parser. Then your regexp will remove too little, and you'll have script garbage in your text.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, parsing clean HTML and XML should be in LL(1). So a parser for this should be faster than a full regexp engine (which may need to do backtracking). So a regexp could be slower (but most will be able to compile easy regexpe into DFAs). So either way, using a XML parser *should* be acceptable. Just the full bsoup in pure python may be too slow. But why remove the scripts when you then don't parse the HTML? And removing them first won't significantly speed up your HTML parsing.