# Error "No module named '__builtin__'" when importing warc

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, warc

How to use `warc` package in python 3 ?

I installed `warc` with no problem. But when I call `import warc` I am getting the error:

> Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError No module named
> '**builtin**'

Comment: This `warc` thing hasn't been maintained since 2012. Migrate to something else. [`warcio` looks like it does the same job.](https://pypi.org/project/warcio/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module __builin__ is a python 2 name. If you want a python3-compatible package that reads warcs, I suggest 'warcio'.